# Human eye image compression

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-compression

I want to find a computationly efficient way to compress picture in a way that human eye works. Given a normal high resolution picture we leave original high resolution in focus center. This could be just center of original picture and the more l2 distance is from the center less pixel resolution is used. So we have maximal resolution in center and  minimal on the borders.  We are not just bluring image on border we are skiping pixels maybe using some standard interpolation. So image will be significantly smaller than the original. I can imagine how to develop such algorithm using a pixel by pixel for loop. But how to do the computationaly effective? Is there some  ready to use approach that I can use? Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Interesting question. But human eye works in a very different way. Have a look at this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4I5Q3UXkGd0   . The temporal aspect and brain's 3D cognition are also involved.

Comment: I think that video tells the same. low resolution out if center